How does salt water compare against chlorinated water in terms of long-term damage on diving masks?
I have the option to swim in salt water (sea) or in chlorinated water (swimming pool). How does salt water compare against chlorinated water in terms of long-term damage on diving masks?

Scuba diving with gear or just snorkeling with a mask? (In either case, I wonder what wildlife you expect to see in the pool?)

@PMF diving mask only (no snorkeling and no scuba)

You probably won't notice a difference, even if you left your mask in the water for several years. Masks are made of some kind of plastic and (for expensive ones) with glass windows. Neither plastic nor glass are much affected by salt water or chlorine, and as we all know, plastic garbage in the oceans does not rot. The one thing that does affect plastic is UV light, that's what makes it age. So if you keep your mask (deep) underwater, it's likely it even survives longer than in the sun, as Water is quite a good UV filter.
The only thing I could imagine is that the chlorinated pool could make the mask smell a bit. Sea water on the other hand does normally not smell.
Check also this related question.

+1 because answer IS useful, but it may not be totally complete.  Material at https://scubaboard.com/community/threads/what-are-the-effects-of-chlorine-on-scuba-gear.58969/ may add further info.  Also, consider effect on small ancillary components, such as sealants.   From the source I listed, rinsing is a very effective precaution against chlorine  damage and discoloration that entails minimal effort.

Glass. All diving masks are made out of glass. Except for FFMs, but these aren't consumer hardware.
